# Unable to place a return order in ATG

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo, atg-droplet

I was trying place a return order in ATG by pushing some xml in Aux-Agent server. During execution
geting below exception. Any idea about this error. I am unable to find the root cause.

Caused by: CONTAINER:atg.service.pipeline.RunProcessException: An exception was thrown from the context of the link named [cloneOriginalOrder].; SOURCE:java.lang.NullPointerException
at atg.service.pipeline.PipelineChain.runProcess(PipelineChain.java:394)
at atg.service.pipeline.PipelineChainContext.runProcess(PipelineChainContext.java:207)
at atg.service.pipeline.PipelineManager.runProcess(PipelineManager.java:475)
at atg.commerce.pipeline.CommercePipelineManager.runProcess(CommercePipelineManager.java:123)
at atg.commerce.order.edit.CloneEditManager.initializeOrderEdit(CloneEditManager.java:434)
... 172 more

Answer (score 0):

As part of the clone order process system will invoke following components to copy actual order data into cloned order. Custom attributes need to map under property 'propertiesToCopyOnUpdate' and any mismatch in this mapping will result this issue.

```
/atg/commerce/custsvc/order/edit/OrderPropertyHandler
/atg/commerce/custsvc/order/edit/HandlingInstructionHandler
/atg/commerce/custsvc/order/edit/CommerceItemHandler
/atg/commerce/custsvc/order/edit/ShippingGroupHandler
/atg/commerce/custsvc/order/edit/PaymentGroupHandler
/atg/commerce/custsvc/order/edit/RelationshipHandler
/atg/commerce/custsvc/order/edit/ManualAdjustmentHandler
/atg/commerce/custsvc/order/edit/AgentCommentHandler
/atg/commerce/custsvc/order/edit/MarkerHandler
/atg/commerce/custsvc/order/edit/GWPOrderMarkerHandler
```